# Why my MaybeConst concept doesn't resolve properly in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have the following concept:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
concept MaybeConst = std::is_same_v<U, std::remove_cv_t<T>>;
```

And a use-case for it looks like this (it's and example you can actually try):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>


template<typename T, typename U>
concept MaybeConst = std::is_same_v<U, std::remove_cv_t<T>>;


class String {};


class Value {
protected:
    double number = 0;
public:
    Value & operator=(const Value & value) {
        number = value.number;
        return *this;
    }
    Value & operator=(const wchar_t * value) {
        number = 0;
        return *this;
    }
    Value & operator=(MaybeConst<String> auto & value) {
        number = 0;
        return *this;
    }
};

String getString() {
    return {};
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Value someValue;

    someValue = getString();

    return 0;
}
```

In the end, the compiler doesn't even count `operator=(MaybeConst<String> auto & value)` as an option when matching definitions and arguments.

It just says it's ambiguous what to chose between `operator=(const Value & value)` and `operator=(const wchar_t * value)`:

```
ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Value’ and ‘String’)
note: candidate: ‘Value& Value::operator=(const Value&)’
note: candidate: ‘Value& Value::operator=(const wchar_t*)’
```

The only compiler flag is `-fconcepts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to bind an rvalue to `auto &`. This will not work since the `auto` will never deduce to a const-qualified type for a non-const rvalue (`auto &` is meant for lvalues). You want to use a forwarding reference instead:

```cpp
template<typename T> requires MaybeConst<std::remove_reference_t<T>, String>
Value & operator=(T && value) {
    number = 0;
    return *this;
}

// Or
template<typename T, typename U>
concept IsSameDecayed = std::is_same_v<U, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;


Value & operator=(IsSameDecayed<String> auto && value) {
    number = 0;
    return *this;
}
```

Or you can just have a two overloads:

```cpp
private:
void assign_string(auto & value) {
    // decltype(value) is `const String&` or `String&`
}

public:
Value & operator=(      String & value) { assign_string(value); return *this; } 
Value & operator=(const String & value) { assign_string(value); return *this; }
```

Where `someValue = getString();` will pick the `const String &` overload

Comment: @Barry Looks like I was mistaken about how constraints work in abbreviated function templates. I've fixed it now